# Has anyone just "built a tower"?

Tags: building

I've heard stories about it, but has anyone simply built a "tower" out of lego pieces and bricks? By a tower I mean lots of bricks on top of each other.

Answer (score 12):

It's actually quite a common thing to build. So much so that TLG has held a number of tower building events at their theme parks and at other locations. Here's a photo of what I believe is the current world record. This was completed in Prague and is 32.5 meters tall.

[image]

Comment: A significantly smaller scale one, built this summer during a FreeLUG meeting, with no other tools than a ladder: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4HYkZNR_ryc